# How can I change the connection node across a solution of SSMS scripts?

Tags: sql-server, connection-string, ssms, replace

**The background:** I work with an SSMS solution (2008 R2, but doubt that matters) that has hundreds of `.sql` files. I work on it in several different environments, using a `(local)` a `(local)\namedinstance`, a `differentserver`, etc. The `.ssmssqlproj` files store a "default"`ConnectionNode` element for each of the files opened in whatever environment last connected.

**The problem:** Each time I move the solution to a new environment and open any of the .sql files, SSMS hangs trying to connect to a server that isn't there, before prompting me to choose a new server. This is a repetitive annoyance, but heavens forfend I should launch a `Replace in Files` operation with the option to keep changed files open: I am stuck in a loop as it does this to each and every file until I blow the process up and go get a taco.

**The question:** What's the best, fastest way to reset all these connection nodes? I assume some sort of command-line script, and tried [FART](http://fart-it.sourceforge.net/) which looks great, but there are lots of escape characters and I couldn't get it working (very little documentation of complex find/replace ops). Is that even the best option? Does SSMS/SQL Server have some tool/extension for this I'm not familiar with?